# Слова после точки с запятой в конце рубрик перечисления всегда пишутся со строчной буквы?

Tags: пунктуация, орфография, оформление-текста, знак

Пример.

Такой способ употребления мин заставил предъявить к ним требования:

1. чтобы оторвавшаяся от якоря и плавающая на поверхности мина не могла повредить натолкнувшееся на нее судно;
2. чтобы при постановке заграждения не было всплывших мин, могущих указать место заграждения, и такие мины тонули.

Также вопрос касается презентаций, когда вместо цифр используется круглый символ для обозначения пункта.
Ниже уточню на примере, который написан в презентации, которую я просматриваю.
Примеры целей:
● Купить себе новый телефон;
● Подарить маме книгу;
● Съездить в отпуск.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, после точки с запятой пишется строчная буква, но тогда после цифр перечня должна стоять скобка. Я бы добавил ещё слово "следующие".

*Такой способ употребления мин заставил предъявить к ним **следующие** требования:*
*1) чтобы оторвавшаяся от якоря и плавающая на поверхности мина не могла повредить натолкнувшееся на нее судно;

2) чтобы при постановке заграждения не было всплывших мин, могущих указать место заграждения, и такие мины тонули;

3) увеличить безопасность постановки мин.*

> Со строчной буквы начинается текст каждого элемента в перечне, если ему предшествует **цифра со скобкой**:
>
> 1) новое и старое;
> 2) старое и новое.

Если после цифры стоит точка, текст после неё пишется с заглавной буквы, в конце пункта тоже ставится точка.

[**Как оформлять перечни?**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/83-rubric-77) (Грамота.ру)

Дополнение (после добавления в вопросе)

Посмотрите, как на Грамоте оформлены два перечня с точками вместо букв или цифр. Всё точно так же: строчная буква, точка с запятой в конце.

Примеры целей:
● купить себе новый телефон;
● подарить маме книгу;
● съездить в отпуск.

Часто в презентациях, где используют эти жирные точки, вообще не ставят никаких знаков в конце пунктов.

Примеры целей:
● Купить себе новый телефон
● Подарить маме книгу
● Съездить в отпуск

Comment: Благодарю за ответ! Я дополнила свой вопрос, вернее его описание, потому буду признательна за уточнение.

Comment: @Милана Посмотрите, как на Грамоте (ссылка в ответе) оформлены два перечня с точками вместо букв или цифр. Всё точно так же: если пишем с большой буквы, то в конце пункта ставим точку (или вообще без всяких знаков в конце), если с маленькой – запятую или точку с запятой.